# run console one time inside map function using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, nodes

I have an array and I want to store its variable in files as I have declare files outside the map function

```js
let object = [
  {
    id: '01',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'maths',
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    name: null,
    'Data.type': 'science',
  },
  {
    id: '04',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  },
  {
    id: '05',
    name: null,
    'Data.type': 'node',
  },{
    id: '01',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'maths',
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'science',
  },
  {
    id: '04',
    name: null,
    'Data.type': 'node',
  },
  {
    id: '05',
    name: null,
    'Data.type': 'node',
  }
];
let names=[];
object.map((value) => {
  if(typeof value.name === "string"){
  names.push(value.name);
  console.log(names);
  }
//some code here
//code here
// use of names to perform some task
})
```

the value is printed like this

```
["subject"]

["subject",
 "language"]

["subject",
 "language",
 "subject"]

["subject",
 "language",
 "subject",
 "subject"]
```

is there any possibility it should only run 1 time inside map function with fully loaded value inside like this so i can perform task inside the map function

```
files= ["subject",
 "language",
 "subject",
 "subject"]
```

Comment: yes - `let names = object.map((value) => { ... })` then `console.log(names);`

Comment: Why don't you move the `console.log` outside the `map`? Also why `map` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: hi @GuerricP as i need others key value to perform some task that's why i am using map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

The purpose of `array.map` is to create a new array where each element is changed to the result of the original element gone through the provided function.

### For example,

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];

function times2(n) {
  return n * 2;
}

var b = a.map(times2);
console.log(b); // Will log [2, 4, 5]
```

## [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

There is also the function `array.forEach`. The purpose of this is to run a function with each element of the array as an input in order.

### For example,

```
a = [1, 2, 3];

a.forEach(console.log); // Will log: "1", then "2", then "3".
```

## Your solution:

You are wanting to run a function on each element of your array.

Your function should take one element as an input, and push it to another existing array.

You should wait until every element has been added to the new array to log it.

### For example,

```
let names = [];

function addToNames(element) {
  if (typeof element.name === "string") {
    names.push(element.name);
  }
}

object.forEach(addToNames);
console.log(names);
// Now that names array is complete, you can do whatever you need with it.
```

### Another option, using arrow functions,

```
let names = [];

object.forEach(element => {
  if (typeof element.name === "string") {
    names.push(element.name);
  }
});
console.log(names);
// Now that names array is complete, you can do whatever you need with it.
```